# Read images to a pre-allocated numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm doing some *fast* image processing in Python (with Numpy/Scipy + OpenCV).
There are several thousand images which are exactly the same shape - once I read the first one, I know exactly how all others will look like.

The problem is that **reading** every next image **from disk** causes allocation of new memory (which is slow). Is there a way to avoid it by reading every next image directly into some already existing memory (`ndarray`)? I know of [cv2.imdecode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imdecode) which in C++ can accept a pointer to pre-allocated Mat, but it does not seem to have a Python binding (the only option is to return a whole new array).

I need this for multiprocessing - I'd like to read images into a shared memory, then do some heavy work on them in worker processes. Right now I'm forced to copy data from the array allocated and returned by [cv2.imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread) into that shared memory, which again takes time. I'd like to be able to write there directly.

Comment: This sounds like a useful PR for OpenCV. What file format are you using? It might be possible to use one of the lower level libraries.

Comment: Do you have profiler data that shows that your bottleneck really is in memory allocation? If that's the case, why don't you slowly read your images into a tensor and cache that tensor to disk?

Comment: @NilsWerner It's not the memory allocation alone being a bottleneck. It's also the copy to subprocess which does some work with the image - either during sending data over a pipe, or during a copy from OpenCV-allocated buffer onto the shared memory. I would like to read data directly to that shared memory, with one stone killing both the allocation and copy birds ;)

MadPhysicist Right now I'm using PNG, but eventually I'd like to have a more general kind of solution.

Comment: I also face the same problem. I want to capture frame into a pre-allocated numpy array. Could you share me your solution ? Now, I have to write a C extension to call C/C++ api, and wrap a new function which accepts a numpy buffer pointer.

Comment: nobody has found a way to do this??

Answer (score -1):

```
height, width = (50, 50)
image = np.zeros((height, width))
id(image)
# outputs: 140411457307552
image[:, :] = np.ones((height, width))
id(image)
# outputs: 140411457307552
image = np.ones((height, width))
id(image)
# outputs -> 140411437723280

# when reading from disk (assuming your images are 50x50 pixels)
image[:, :] = cv2.imread("/home/.../your_im_50x50.png")
```

By addressing each image's dimensions python will try to store the given array into the existing one. This results in a memory assignation to the pre-allocated memory zone. If arrays do not have the same shape it will raise a ValueError. 
When mentioning only the variable name, a new reference to the array is created, resulting in a new object in memory (cf ids)

Comment: While a good hint, it completely ignores the fact that I want to *read data from disk* and put it directly into this memory. However, you made me realize that my question could be clearer about this, so I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: cv2.imread returns numpy.ndarray objects. That's why it is the exact same thing to do  `image[:, :] = np.ones(...)` and `image[:, :] = cv2.imread("/home/.../your_im.png")`

Comment: And that's why you're missing the point of the question. The `imread` call already created the new buffer. Fancy copying doesn't get you out of that. You may as well just drop the old buffer outright and replace with the new at that point.